# Remove sensitive values in a source file and comment the respective fields - using SED / AWK

Tags: regex, shell, sed, awk, ksh

A classical SED / AWK Question.

```
 #Input file 
    #param1=v1
    #param2=v2
    #Param3=v3
     user=u1
     pass=p1
```

after running through command o/p should be like this :

```
 #Input file 
    #param1=v1
    #param2=v2
    #Param3=v3
    #user=
    #pass=
```

To explain what is happening . I dont want the above sensitive info to be left in the file 
So I will find these strings and knock of the values ( I already did this in SED as will be obvious below ). SED reads 1 line at a time. So while it has grabbed that line I want to do a conditional change. IF there is a # before the user then Dont mess  BUT if there is NO Pound ( # ) before it - put it a the beginning of the line. 
So for the 1st part here is what i have

```
sed 's/usr=.*/usr=/g' filename
```

What i want is

- the 2nd part  :  conditional change. IF there is a # before the user
  then Dont mess  BUT if there is NO Pound ( # ) before it - put it at
  the beginning of the line.
- can we run the same steps  for the pass= string in 1 command

Devnull-Thanks you . When I use the command I get these results

```
export usr=pass
#export usr=pass



sed -e '/^ *#/b a' -e 's/\(usr=\).*/#\1/' -e :a file

export #usr=
#export usr=pass
```

@NeronLeVelu
THx. It actually comments the wrong place. 
input file

```
export usr=val
# Either case will be present as line above or line below - not both 
#export usr=val
```

Desired output

```
 #export usr=
 #export usr=
```

What this sed does

```
export #usr=
#export usr=val
```

THANKS SO MUCH folks. ALL the below work .Including 1 from paxdiablo which is the simple form to work up from . The one I chose actually handles both values in 1 pass .Much as I could say the "thx" - I voted up all the answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with an input file (filename = 'in') of:

```
 #Input file
    #param1=v1
    #param2=v2
    #Param3=v3
     usr=u1
     pass=p1

     export usr=u1
        export pass=p1
```

the command:

```
sed -E -e 's/^([ \t]*)#?(export )?usr=.*/\1#\2usr=/g' -e 's/^([ \t]*)#?(export )?pass=.*/\1#\2pass=/g' in
```

produces the result:

```
 #Input file
    #param1=v1
    #param2=v2
    #Param3=v3
     #usr=
     #pass=

     #export usr=
        #export pass=
```

(note that the last line is preceded by a tab instead of spaces like the previous lines were.)

(edit: added `#?` to command to also allow it to remove usr and pass values from already commented out lines.)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all those entries are at the start of the line, simply use:

```
s/^user=/#user=/
```

The `^` anchors the search string to the start of the line so that `#user=whatever` won't match.

Answer (score 1):

You could use label and branch:

```
sed -e '/^ *#/b a' -e 's/\(.*user=\).*/#\1/' -e :a inputfile
```

It'd *comment* out a `user=` line that's already not commented and remove the part after `=`.

For example, it'd transform the following:

```
 user=u1
user=u1
 #user=
#user=u1
```

into:

```
 #user=
#user=
 #user=
#user=u1
```

For *in-place* editing, use the `-i` option:

```
sed -i -e '/^ *#/b a' -e 's/\(.*user=\).*/#\1/' -e :a inputfile
```

---

EDIT: As per your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22033135/how-do-you-do-this-in-sed-awk/22033288?noredirect=1#comment33426110_22033288), the following might work for you:

```
sed -i -e 's/\(.*user=\).*/\1/' -e '/^ *#/b a' -e '/user=/s/^/#/' -e :a inputfile
```

Comment: Hi Thx. Can you give an 'in place' SED command - dont o/p to std o/p but change  the file itself - the -i option I think would do it but not sure where to make that change in the above command

Comment: @user1874594 Refer to the edit above.  It should fix the issue you were encountering.

Comment: Hi thx. What I want to do is  a ) remove the value commented or not  and b) if those fields are not commented then go ahead comment them out

Comment: Hi thx. I handles `#export usr=val` and makes it `#export usr=` as expected. THe 2nd situation is handled with `#` in the wrong place. So `export usr=val` is now `export #usr=` but it should be `#export usr=`

Comment: @user1874594 Should be fixed now.  Check the update.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/\( *\)#/ !{s/\([^ =]*\)=.*/#\1=/;s/^  / /;}' YourFile
```

keep also indentation

should certainly add `--posix` and  `-e` for GNU sed

under AIX/KSH/(non GNU) sed

```
$ cat YourFile
 #Input file
    #param1=v1
    #param2=v2
    #Param3=v3
     user=u1
     pass=p1
$ sed '/\( *\)#/ !{s/\([^ =]*\)=.*/#\1=/;s/^  / /;}' YourFile
 #Input file
    #param1=v1
    #param2=v2
    #Param3=v3
    #user=
    #pass=
```

Comment: It actually comments the wrong place. I will update Q with the o/p

Comment: i just retest, fine on my AIX, try adding --posix option if you are using GNU sed